# Pandas: Handling Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering Dataframes like the ones below, I'm trying to add the `description` column from `df2` to `df`, through the `merge` function

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp': [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,1],
                    'Description': ['Forward', 'Middle', 'Forward', 'back', 'winger', 'Ponta', 'Latera', 'Forward']})

df.merge(df2, on='id_emp', how = 'inner')
```

output:

[image]

The expected output was a dataframe with the number of lines equal to df, adding only the description column. As it stands, the dataframe adds values equal to the total number of times they are in the two dataframes.

So, how can I do that there is no addition of rows in the final dataframe?

Comment: Use left instead of inner merge: `df.merge(df2, on='id_emp', how = 'left')`

Comment: does not work either

Comment: You have duplicate references to ID 1 in `df2`, so you also need to drop duplicates in that DataFrame: `df.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on='id_emp', how = 'left')`

Comment: It worked, but with inner instead of left.